# Help on getting a Greek new testament and a Hebrew Bible

Tags: greek, hebrew

Can I receive some help? I'm currently learning biblical Languages and don't have any physical copies of the critical NA28 text and the BHS. I'm in a country with no access to physical copies of these books (and poverty too) so can I get help for me to receive these books?

Comment: [Link](http://www.greekdoc.com).

Comment: Do you need a physical copy, or would an online text be enough?

Comment: Some are free here https://www.olivetree.com/store/home.php?cat=279&sort=price_asc

Comment: online MT https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=Genesis&version=WLC

Comment: Online versions are far superior and free and incomparable to any hard copy especially those books. Download MyBible app on phone and use logos Bible software and theword for reading versions. All free.

Comment: A physical copy for me is better for studying

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Open Greek New Testament, which attempts to be a free NA28 equivalent: https://opengnt.com

Comment: Hi Phil, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lucian provided great links for Greek.

For Hebrew:

HBS with morpholigical tagging:
https://hb.openscriptures.org

Also, check out an online interlinear bible with morphological tags:

https://marvel.bible/index.php?text=MIB&b=1&c=1&v=1